# How can I modify the access timestamp of a file to seconds before using a shell command in unix?

Tags: shell, date, unix, timestamp, touch

I try to change the access time of a file to seconds before, for example to set "**1437082451**" (**07/16/2015 @ 9:34:11pm (UTC)**) to "**1437082450**" (**07/16/2015 @ 9:34:10pm (UTC)**) 
So I just substract one second to the current access time.
I have to do so with only shell commands, I searched for a while but can't find nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
touch -at $(date -d @$(( $(stat -c '%X' "$filename") - 1)) '+%Y%m%d%H%M.%S') "$filename"
```

That uses `stat` to retrieve the current access time of the file, bash arithmetic to subtract one second, and `date` to format the new time for the `touch` command.